# Can I retrieve a users subscription info from paypal at any time?

Tags: paypal, subscription, paypal-ipn

I need to determine when a user's paypal subscription is set to end/renew.  I know that the easiest way to do this would be to extrapolate it from the time when the initial subscr_signup gets sent through, based on the subscription interval value, but because I'm working with some 3rd party software, it's not possible (or at least, not ideal).

It seems to me that I ought to be able to send a query to paypal to get this info based on txn_id, but I can't find any documentation that implies that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

if you send a request with:

```
TRXTYPE = R -this is to tell it recurring profiles  
ACTION = I - this is to tell it to make an inquiry
ORIGPROFILEID = XXX - this is the profile you want to look up
PAYMENTHISTORY = N - this will tell it not to return payment history
```

from there the array will return something like this:

```
RESULT[1]=0
RPREF[12]=XXXXX
PROFILEID[12]=XXX
STATUS[6]=ACTIVE
PROFILENAME[1]=0
START[8]=10182006
TERM[1]=0
NEXTPAYMENT[8]=10182009
PAYPERIOD[4]=QTER
TENDER[1]=C
AMT[5]=0.00
ACCT[16]=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
EXPDATE[4]=0101
AGGREGATEAMT[6]=0.00
AGGREGATEOPTIONALAMT[5]=0.00
MAXFAILPAYMENTS[1]=0
NUMFAILPAYMENTS[1]=1
RETRYNUMDAYS[1]=4
NAME[11]=BLAHBLAH
ZIP[5]=12345
```

What you are looking for is the START, but pretty much all the items in the array are self explanitory.

Comment: This sounds like what I need, but what URL do I send it to - and I assume those variables need to be POSTed?  Also, is the ORIGPROFILEID the txn_id, or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: A little more research, and it looks like what youre referring to is for the paypal recurring payments api,via payflow pro.  I need to do the same thing, except with a paypal managed subscription, which uses IPNs to receive the subscription information initially.